# Applying gaussian blur to images in a loop

Tags: numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have a simple ndarray with shape as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.imshow(trainImg[0])  #can display a sample image
print(trainImg.shape) : (4750, 128, 128, 3)  #shape of the dataset
```

I intend to apply **`Gaussian blur`** to all the images. The for loop I went with:

```
trainImg_New = np.empty((4750, 128, 128,3)) 
for idx, img in enumerate(trainImg):
  trainImg_New[idx] = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
```

I tried to display a sample blurred image as:

```
plt.imshow(trainImg_New[0])  #view a sample blurred image
```

but I get an error:

```
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).
```

It just displays a blank image.

Comment: What about `plt.imshow(np.uint8(trainImg_New[0]))`?

Comment: great. yes this was the issue! thnx

Comment: You mean "several images", not "images in a loop", otherwise it's an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). As one of the answers says, you don't have to write a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:
The error is most likely caused by `trainImg_New` is float datatype and its value is larger than 1. So, as @Frightera mentioned, try using `np.uint8` to convert images' datatype.

I tested the snippets as below:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

trainImg_New = np.random.rand(4750, 128, 128,3) # all value is in range [0, 1]
save = np.empty((4750, 128, 128,3))
for idx, img in enumerate(trainImg_New):
  save[idx] = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)

plt.imshow(np.float32(save[0]+255)) # Reported error as question
plt.imshow(np.float32(save[0]+10)) # Reported error as question
plt.imshow(np.uint8(save[0]+10)) # Good to go
```

First of all, `cv2.GaussianBlur` will not change the range of the arrays' value and the original image arrays's value is legitimate. So I believe the only reason is the datatype of the `trainImg_New[0]` is not match its range.

So I tested the snippets above, we can see when the datatype of `trainImg_New[0]` matter the available range of the arrays' value.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [`tfa.image.gaussian_filter2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/gaussian_filter2d) from the `tensorflow_addons` package. I think you'll be able to pass all your images at once.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage import data
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = data.astronaut()

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
blurred = tfa.image.gaussian_filter2d(image, 
                                      filter_shape=(25, 25), 
                                      sigma=3.)

plt.imshow(blurred)
plt.show()
```

[image]